# how to create a Server in PHP and client in JAVA

Tags: java, php, web-services, websocket, server

I like to implement server as backend server service and front as a regular website using php..Is it possible to create like this.Also how can integrate this by using a java swing application as client (client is on localhost)?

Comment: This question is far too broad.  People can write several books on these topics and barely scratch the surface of what this question is asking.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [web services](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/). So you can create server in php and client in java.